# Sed replace word except when word is preceded by a specific string

Tags: text-processing, sed

I want to replace all instance of `abc` with `123` provided it isn't preceded by `https://`.

Code:

```
file=Data.txt
Initial="# Start";
orig="abc";
new="123"; 

Final="$" # Line Number
sed -r -e "/${Initial}/,${Final}s/${orig}/${new}/g" ${file} # Final doesn't accept $
```

Data:

```
# Start

abc.md
https://abc.md
The path is https://abc.md for abc.md
The path for abc.md is https://abc.md
```

Expected Output:

```
# Start

123.md
https://abc.md
The path is https://abc.md for 123.md
The path for 123.md is https://abc.md
```

How can I achieve this?

---

Note: I also need to use `${Initial}` and  `${Final}` to denote between which the pattern might exist.

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/487727/220462) doesn't work for the case `The path is: https://abc.md abc.md`

Comment: Would you be happy with a solution that uses line numbers (not regular expressions for addressing the relevant bit of the input)?

Comment: @Kusalananda No, because the line numbers are nof fixed.

Comment: Is the substitution _always_ happening from the matching of some pattern and to the end of the file?

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes the substitution happens between ${Iniital} and to end of the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is *negative-look-behind*, which neither `sed` or `awk` supports. I recommend going with `perl`, e.g.:

```
file=Data.txt
export Initial="# Start"
export orig="abc"
export new="123"
export Final="5"

perl -pe '
 $flag=1 if /$ENV{Initial}/;
 s,(?<!https://)$ENV{orig},$ENV{new},g if $flag;
 $flag=0 if $. == $ENV{Final};
' $file
```

Comment: Does not work with `The path is https://abc.md for abc.md` as per the OP's updated requirement. I updated my answer, and I think you can update yours ;-)

Comment: @sudodus: It does if it occurs before the `Final` line, line number 5 in the above example

Comment: You are right about that. (A bit difficult to see for a perl illiterate, but it works) :-)

Comment: @Thor How to make `Final` as the last line? In `sed` we use `$`.

Comment: Just remove `$flag=0 if $. == $ENV{Final};`

Comment: @Nikhil: You can also set `Final` to 0, which will never be true

Answer (score 2):

You could temporarily change all instances that start with `https://`to something else, not containing `abc`, and change them back when you've finished.

## Lazy method

```
sed -e 's_https://abc_protected_g;/# Start/,$s_abc_123_g;s_protected_https://abc_'
```

You'll have to pick some value for the temporary string, that you can be certain won't appear in your input (and doesn't contain any special characters that would interfere with `sed` or shell quoting).  I used `protected` but something more distinctive is advisable.

## Thorough method

If you can't be certain that your temporary string won't occur in the input, a longer but safer alternative would be to use *two* replacement strings:

```
sed -e 's/X/Xv/g;s_https://abc_Xu_g;/^# Start/,$s/abc/123/g;s_Xu_https://abc_g;s/Xv/X/g'
```

The requirements of these two temporary strings are:

- They have a common prefix (I used `X`, but it can be longer/more readable)
- They don't occur within the other variables: `orig`, `new`, `Initial` or `Final`
- As before, they don't contain characters that would break the `sed` expression

Comment: It is interesting to see PCRE features implemented in a pure BRE way, in a single `sed` invocation. I am wondering whether other PCRE features have their equivalents as well.

Comment: @WeijunZhou As noted [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176026/whats-wrong-with-my-lookahead-regex-in-gnu-sed/12178023?noredirect=1#comment94399885_12178023) this does not reimplement negative lookaheads, only the subproblem of negative lookaheads with a static string. Some Perl / PCRE extensions are purely convenience / syntactic sugar which is straightforward (but often cumbersome or boring) to replace with traditional regex, but e.g. lookarounds genuinely extend the formalism to something which is no longer theoretically equivalent (reducible) to regular expressions.

Comment: There is no contradiction. A PCRE not being reducible to regular expression is one thing, and I agree on that. Using `sed` to modify the text to assist in pattern matching is another thing, which is no longer simple pattern patching and hence does not contradict. To put it more clearly, there is still no way to use `grep` to match lookaround patterns with BRE or ERE.